# Textures not appearing in minecraft mod

Tags: java, eclipse, textures, minecraft

I am trying to mod minecraft 1.11.2 in eclipse and I put all the texure files in the right place but they just won't load. I tried rewriting some of the java to see if I had made a mistake but nothing changed.
This is my error code:

```
[11:22:57] [Client thread/INFO]: Created: 16x16 textures-atlas
[11:23:00] [Client thread/ERROR] [FML]: Exception loading model for variant wowkcraft:itemobsidianingot#inventory for item "wowkcraft:itemobsidianingot", normal location exception: 
net.minecraftforge.client.model.ModelLoaderRegistry$LoaderException: Exception loading model wowkcraft:item/itemobsidianingot with loader VanillaLoader.INSTANCE, skipping
    at net.minecraftforge.client.model.ModelLoaderRegistry.getModel(ModelLoaderRegistry.java:153) ~[ModelLoaderRegistry.class:?]
    at net.minecraftforge.client.model.ModelLoader.loadItemModels(ModelLoader.java:323) ~[ModelLoader.class:?]
    at net.minecraft.client.renderer.block.model.ModelBakery.loadVariantItemModels(ModelBakery.java:175) ~[ModelBakery.class:?]
    at net.minecraftforge.client.model.ModelLoader.setupModelRegistry(ModelLoader.java:153) ~[ModelLoader.class:?]
    at net.minecraft.client.renderer.block.model.ModelManager.onResourceManagerReload(ModelManager.java:28) [ModelManager.class:?]
    at net.minecraft.client.resources.SimpleReloadableResourceManager.registerReloadListener(SimpleReloadableResourceManager.java:122) [SimpleReloadableResourceManager.class:?]
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.init(Minecraft.java:541) [Minecraft.class:?]
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.run(Minecraft.java:387) [Minecraft.class:?]
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(Main.java:118) [Main.class:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.launch(Launch.java:135) [launchwrapper-1.12.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.main(Launch.java:28) [launchwrapper-1.12.jar:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at net.minecraftforge.gradle.GradleStartCommon.launch(GradleStartCommon.java:97) [start/:?]
    at GradleStart.main(GradleStart.java:26) [start/:?]
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: wowkcraft:models/item/itemobsidianingot.json
    at net.minecraft.client.resources.FallbackResourceManager.getResource(FallbackResourceManager.java:69) ~[FallbackResourceManager.class:?]
    at net.minecraft.client.resources.SimpleReloadableResourceManager.getResource(SimpleReloadableResourceManager.java:65) ~[SimpleReloadableResourceManager.class:?]
    at net.minecraft.client.renderer.block.model.ModelBakery.loadModel(ModelBakery.java:334) ~[ModelBakery.class:?]
    at net.minecraftforge.client.model.ModelLoader.access$1600(ModelLoader.java:124) ~[ModelLoader.class:?]
    at net.minecraftforge.client.model.ModelLoader$VanillaLoader.loadModel(ModelLoader.java:923) ~[ModelLoader$VanillaLoader.class:?]
    at net.minecraftforge.client.model.ModelLoaderRegistry.getModel(ModelLoaderRegistry.java:149) ~[ModelLoaderRegistry.class:?]
    ... 20 more
[11:23:00] [Client thread/ERROR] [FML]: Exception loading model for variant wowkcraft:itemobsidianingot#inventory for item "wowkcraft:itemobsidianingot", blockstate location exception: 
net.minecraftforge.client.model.ModelLoaderRegistry$LoaderException: Exception loading model wowkcraft:itemobsidianingot#inventory with loader VariantLoader.INSTANCE, skipping
    at net.minecraftforge.client.model.ModelLoaderRegistry.getModel(ModelLoaderRegistry.java:153) ~[ModelLoaderRegistry.class:?]
    at net.minecraftforge.client.model.ModelLoader.loadItemModels(ModelLoader.java:331) ~[ModelLoader.class:?]
    at net.minecraft.client.renderer.block.model.ModelBakery.loadVariantItemModels(ModelBakery.java:175) ~[ModelBakery.class:?]
    at net.minecraftforge.client.model.ModelLoader.setupModelRegistry(ModelLoader.java:153) ~[ModelLoader.class:?]
    at net.minecraft.client.renderer.block.model.ModelManager.onResourceManagerReload(ModelManager.java:28) [ModelManager.class:?]
    at net.minecraft.client.resources.SimpleReloadableResourceManager.registerReloadListener(SimpleReloadableResourceManager.java:122) [SimpleReloadableResourceManager.class:?]
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.init(Minecraft.java:541) [Minecraft.class:?]
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.run(Minecraft.java:387) [Minecraft.class:?]
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(Main.java:118) [Main.class:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.launch(Launch.java:135) [launchwrapper-1.12.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.main(Launch.java:28) [launchwrapper-1.12.jar:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at net.minecraftforge.gradle.GradleStartCommon.launch(GradleStartCommon.java:97) [start/:?]
    at GradleStart.main(GradleStart.java:26) [start/:?]
Caused by: net.minecraft.client.renderer.block.model.ModelBlockDefinition$MissingVariantException
    at net.minecraft.client.renderer.block.model.ModelBlockDefinition.getVariant(ModelBlockDefinition.java:78) ~[ModelBlockDefinition.class:?]
    at net.minecraftforge.client.model.ModelLoader$VariantLoader.loadModel(ModelLoader.java:1239) ~[ModelLoader$VariantLoader.class:?]
    at net.minecraftforge.client.model.ModelLoaderRegistry.getModel(ModelLoaderRegistry.java:149) ~[ModelLoaderRegistry.class:?]
    ... 20 more
```

Answer (score 3):

## Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: wowkcraft:models/item/itemobsidianingot.json

You're missing an Item Model json.  The error is buried a little deeply, as there are several possible errors that lead to a model being unable to load, so the initial error ("failed to load model") is on top of the underlying error (in this case, "file not found").

Taken from the [Documentation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354217/sunsetting-documentation) entries I wrote on the subject, with some minor alterations and updates:

As with blocks, items need models too.

```
{
    "parent": "item/generated",
    "textures": {
        "layer0": "example:items/basic"
    }
}
```

That's pretty much all that's needed for it to work once the item is registered. The only important thing is that the filename match the registry name used to register the block and should be in all lowercase (1.11+ file names are required to be lowercase, prior to that it is just case sensitive).

Name the model JSON file matching the registry name and save it at `src\main\resources\assets\example\models\item\` (where `example` is the mod ID specified in the @Mod annotation of your main mod class).

Additionally create a texture for your item, name it `basic.png` and save it to `src\main\resources\assets\example\textures\items\` (The file is referenced by the model via `"layer0": "example:items/basic"` which says "find a .png file named 'basic' inside the `items` folder of the resource location `example`")

The item model here uses a parent of `item/generated`, which means that the single supplied texture will be used (as with most non-block items) and will be held in the player's hand in a default orientation. There is also `item/handheld` which specifies different display orientations (for tools). Items may also supply their own "display" attribute, overriding those from the parent, but is not needed in 99.9% of uses.

**Registering the item:**

```
Item item = new CustomItem();
string registryname = "my_item";
item.setRegistryName(registryname);
item.setUnlocalizedName(item.getRegistryName().toString());
GameRegistry.register(item);
```

There is an important reason to use `item.setUnlocalizedName(item.getRegistryName().toString());` as well! It insures that your item's unlocalized name contains your mod ID to avoid language file conflicts between mods. It is unlikely, but entirely avoidable.

**Registering the item model:**

```
final ModelResourceLocation fullModelLocation = new ModelResourceLocation(item.getRegistryName().toString(), "inventory");
ModelBakery.registerItemVariants(item, fullModelLocation);
ModelLoader.setCustomMeshDefinition(item, new ItemMeshDefinition()
    {
        public ModelResourceLocation getModelLocation(ItemStack stack)
        {
            return fullModelLocation;
        }
    });
```

Note that this section must be located client-side only (i.e. the client proxy) as many of the referenced classes do not exist on the dedicated server.

Registering items with variants e.g. Saplings, has to be done a different way, using `ModelLoader.setCustomModelResourceLocation(item, metadata, resourceLocation)` although it lets us use a Blockstate file to specify our variants (which is much preferred to the alternative).

#### For 1.12+ modders:

**This also works in 1.11, but is required in 1.12 and forward**

`GameRegistry.register()` is now `private`. Instead you must register things in the `RegistryEvent.Register<T>` event through an event handler. Simply subscribe to the `RegistryEvent.Register<Item>` or `RegistryEvent.Register<Block>` event (as well as others: an event is fired for each registry type) in order to register items and blocks.  Simply call `event.getRegistry().add(...)` or `event.getRegistry().addAll(...)` for every object that needs to be registered. `addAll` will accept an array or list.  You can see an example of this [here](https://github.com/Draco18s/ReasonableRealism/blob/1d6b0c943b05c96969f398720054a07275d2f8be/src/main/java/com/draco18s/hardlib/EasyRegistry.java#L189-L204).

For models, you do the same thing as above, but in the `ModelRegistryEvent` instead. You can see an example of this [here](https://github.com/Draco18s/ReasonableRealism/blob/1d6b0c943b05c96969f398720054a07275d2f8be/src/main/java/com/draco18s/hardlib/client/ClientEasyRegistry.java#L180) although heavily modified to allow for additional variations in models not discussed here (supporting custom MeshDefinitions and StateMappers).